# How can a static method get instance details or do instance specific actions

Tags: java, oop, jvm, instance, static-methods

The below code obviously will **not** compile.

```
public class Machine {
  public int id;
  static Machine staticMethod() { return this; } //compilation error - "Cannot use this in a static context"
  maskId() {   }
}
```

And so it is not possible from **staticMethod()** to
(1) get information specific to any instance of **Machine** Object
(2) perform an action specific to any instance of **Machine** object

*Unless I am missed something really simple.*

How does the static methods of **Thread** Class deal with actions/information of specific thread.
Below are signatures of such methods from java docs [Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html)

> static Thread  currentThread()   //Returns a reference to the currently executing thread object.
>   static void    dumpStack() //Prints a stack trace of the current thread to the standard error stream.

Did I miss something. Or  are these methods (or Thread Class) different. Like Native implementations etc or what so ever but are able to determine the calling instance.

Comment: `currentThread` is a native method. `dumpStack` isn't dependent on any instance, so it doesn't need to do anything special. [Source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Thread.java)

Comment: "current thread" does not equal "the Thread object instance that you call this method on". In fact, if there wasn't a method `currentThread`, there would be no way to get this information.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Exactly. A `native` solution to a chicken-and-egg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Thread` class *is* different because it's dealing with a core JVM (and usually operating-system) construct. [In OpenJDK, it's not only `native` but also annotated with a hint that says that it's built in to the JRE itself instead of provided by an external library.](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/jdk/file/02d65bf86352/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/Thread.java#l264)

Comment: gr8. I have no further specific questions as native implementation is the answer. ***But would like to ask to anyone reading this post or comment:***  can some one point to good reference to study and understand how to implement native classes or methods - (JNI). There benefits and drawbacks and when they should actually be used or when JNI is the only option.

Comment: This is a good starting point: https://blogs.oracle.com/moonocean/entry/a_simple_example_of_jni. The use cases and pros/cons are too broad for a question, it depends on the specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

A thread can ask; which thread am I? at any point. It doesn't need this to be pass to it as an argument as most values do.  There is a `static` `native` method which gives the current thread and from there this object can have instance methods called on it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is done by scheduler,
Here i am mentioning class structure (it is my perception, how it works)

```
class Thread{
static currentThread();

}

Class Scheduler{
//it has queue of all threads and also has track on current running thread 
//queue = {Thread1,Thread2,Thread3,Thread4,Thread5}
// let thread3 is running, whenever a call to Thread3.currentThread come up 
//some how jvm get instance of Thread3 from this queue and returns.

}
```